# Swift caching data using Apollo Client and GraphCool Backend

Tags: ios, swift, caching, graphql, apollo

First of all: I am a beginner to swift, so please excuse, if my question seems to be obvious to many people, but i could not find a satisfying answer for me, after doing some research on the subject "caching".

I have a very simple **GraphCool** Backend setup (using GraphQL query language) and **Apollo**:
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-ios
on the client's side in my swift project.
As my database is going to grow over time, i am already thinking about how to preserve data volume for my users when making GraphQL-queries, i.e. i do not want to fetch all the data, every time the user restarts the app, but instead cache some data in **local storage**. Since i am already using apollo, i would like to know if apollo allows caching on local storage, or do i have to use a third party library to do that?

I am aware that there are 'cachePolicy' options in Apollo, but as i understand them, they are only for memory caching.

(I did not present any of my app's code for this question, because i don't think it gives any additional benefits as my question is basically about caching in Swift.)

Comment: When I pull down data from a database, if I need to access it offline, I store it in CoreData (a local database for iOS) using MagicalRecord.

Comment: Thanks! Does data in coreData stay persisted in local storage, even after app closes, such that data does not have to be reloaded when relaunching the whole application or even restart the iPhone/iPad?